# how does pandas.Series.str.get method work?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas.Series named **matches** like this:

[image]

When I called `pandas.Series.str.get` method on it, it returns a new Series with its values all `NaN`:

[image]

I have read the document [pandas.Series.str.get](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get.html), but still can't understand it.

Comment: It tries to index into whatever objet is there, but that fails for non-indexable types, in which case you'll get `NaN`

Comment: I can't copy/paste images in my editor. Can you use code blocks instead?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What frustrated me was the `dtype` here, which is `object`. So when I tried to call the same method on other non-indexable types, such as integer,  I got AttributeError.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Thanks for your kindness, Mathias. I know what the problem is.

Comment: @Bicheng can you the code that produced an `AttributeError`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `a = pd.Series(np.arange(5))` , execute `a.str.get(1)` will get `AttributeError`, because here `dtype: int32`. In order to make that method work, need to change a's `dtype`. For example, `b = a.astype(np.object)`, then `b.str.get(1)` will work and get all `NaN` values. This is  because string is a subtype of `np.object`.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. Yes, you were frustrated because before it gave an error, but that error isn't thrown in the case of dtype=object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It return second element from iterable, it is same as `str[1]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [[1,2,3], [0,1,3]], "B":['aswed','yuio']})
print (df) 
            A      B
0  [1, 2, 3]  aswed
1  [0, 1, 3]   yuio

df['C'] = df['A'].str.get(1)
df['C1'] = df['A'].str[1]
df['D'] = df['B'].str.get(1)
df['D1'] = df['B'].str[1]
print (df)
           A      B  C  C1  D D1
0  [1, 2, 3]  aswed  2   2  s  s
1  [0, 1, 3]   yuio  1   1  u  u
```